# Why is there no std::size?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

[Scott Meyers](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197), [Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm) and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715919/member-function-vs-nonmember-function?rq=1) are advocating non-member functions over member functions. And with additions such as `std::begin`, `std::cend`, etc, it seems the STL is moving in that direction. If that is the case, why is there no `std::size`?

I assume because it's easy enough to define your own version:

```
namespace std {
    // C++14
    template <typename C>
    decltype(auto) size(const C& c)
    {
        return distance(cbegin(c), cend(c));
    }
}
```

Or am I missing something? i.e. is there a reason **not** to use a non-member `size`?

Comment: [There is now](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4280.pdf) (well, not quite now). [Just voted into the working paper last November](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4251.html) (see LWG motion 20).

Comment: I should also point out that my example `std::size` is not very good!

Comment: You've missed the obvious support for `T[n]`, yes.

Comment: @MSalters and because `std::distance` is O(n), where-as I believe all STL-containers must have O(1) `size` members?

Comment: @Daniel All but `forward_list`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is there no `std::size`?

Because nobody wrote a proposal in time for it to be included in C++14. [The first draft of the proposal to add it](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4017.htm) was dated May 2014, well after the C++14 standard was sent out for its last round of ballot in February 2014.

[A revised version](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4280.pdf) of the proposal was [voted into the C++ working paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4251.html) at the Committee's last meeting in November (see LWG motion 20), so it's likely that you'll see it in the next revision of the standard (C++17?), along with `std::empty()` and `std::data()`.