# Non-member non-friend `std::size()` that works with C-arrays and vectors

Tags: c++, c, stl

There are many [benefits](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) in using non-member non-friend functions. A good example is the use of non-member `std::begin()` instead of member function `.begin(),` since the former will work with C-arrays too, while the latter wouldn't make sense for C-arrays.

It makes more sense to have `std::size()` too, for the same reason we have `std::begin(),` to enable users to write a code like:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
cout << std::size(a); // to print 3
```

Is there any technical issues related to including such a function in the standard?

(Possible implementation would simply be `return end(a) - begin(a);` which would work for both C-arrays and vectors.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498555/why-is-there-no-stdsize

Comment: Your implementation will only work for containers that have random access iterators.

Comment: @user3386109, That's not really relevant. `std::end` works on C arrays and can tell you where the end of the array is. Thus, `std::size` would be possible as well. Neither of these would work for decayed arrays; that hasn't changed.

Comment: @AnT Thanks for the link. I failed to find that link which is the same question as I have.

Answer (score 0):

There are no technical issues. It has been voted into the Working Paper, but it happened after the release of C++14.

[Non-member size() and more (Revision 2)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4280.pdf)

[WG21 2014-11 Urbana Minutes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4251.html)

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size

Expect it to appear in C++17.

P.S. As a side note, the existing `std::extent` can be used to determine the array size, but it does not unify non-container and container interfaces. So, this is not what you are talking about.